# how to add multiple account permissions in eos

Tags: eos

the command is below:

```js
cleos set account permission mcdonald active '{"threshold": 1, "keys": [{"key": "EOS7BZwiFi3nyBi9rQJua6wQv37my7G21YYNZo5ZeVKcGZQNFYEjd", "weight": 1}, {"key": "EOS63ZXCNHSAr9ZqXCpAgLNox4CLYZ2u2oCVnNZeVCSp5W82qLb4i", "weight": 1}], "accounts":[{"permission":{"actor":"mcdonald","permission":"active"},"weight":1}, {"permission":{"actor":"mcdonald","permission":"active"},"weight":1}]}' owner
```

The error message is as follows:
   Authority failed validation! ensure that keys, accounts, and waits are 
   sorted and that the threshold is valid and satisfiable!

What went wrong? I think the format of json should be fine.

Comment: the command (cleos set account permission mcdonald active '{"threshold":1,"keys":[],"accounts":[{"permission":{"actor":"bob","permission":"active"},"weight":1},{"permission":{"actor":"monad","permission":"active"},"weight":1}]}' owner) also don't work。

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
cleos set account permission <your_account> active <contract_account> --add-code
```

for example:

```
cleos set account permission me active bob --add-code
cleos set account permission me active alice --add-code
cleos set account permission me active foo --add-code
cleos set account permission me active bar --add-code
```

then check with `cleos get account me`

output:

> created: 2019-03-01T12:49:08.500
>   permissions:
>       owner     1:    1 EOS6MRyXXXXXXXXXcfnVPJqcVpscN5So8BhtXXXXXX
>       active     1:    1 EOS6MRyXXXXXXXXcfnVPJqcVpscN5So8BhtXXXXXX, 1
>   alice@eosio.code, 1 bob@eosio.code, 1 foo@eosio.code, 1 bar@eosio.code
>   memory:
>       quota:       unlimited  used:     2.785 KiB
>
> net bandwidth:
>       used:               unlimited
>       available:          unlimited
>       limit:              unlimited
>
> cpu bandwidth:
>       used:               unlimited
>       available:          unlimited
>       limit:              unlimited